# How to print the contents of the objects taking one value as input in powershell?

Tags: powershell, for-loop, foreach, hashtable

I need to display the contents related to each id number by taking id as input. The original format was in json, as below:

```
{
    "ids": [
        {
            "id": "121100",
            "Libraries": [
                "cpa_sample_code_s.so",
                "stv_test_code_s.so"
            ],
            "Commands": [
                "qaeMemInit",
                "icp_sal_userStartMultiProcess(\"SSL\",CPA_FALSE)",
                "rsaPerformanceTest(1,0x02,2,10,1000) [RSA API]"
            ],
            "Label": "rsaPerformanceTest-Test"
        },
        {
            "id": "121103",
            "Libraries": [
                "cpa_sample_code_s.so",
                "stv_test_code_s.so"
            ],
            "Commands": [
                "qaeMemInit",
                "icp_sal_userStartMultiProcess(\"SSL\",CPA_FALSE)",
                "dhPerformanceTest(1,0x02,10,10000)"
            ],
            "Label": "dhPerformanceTest-Test"
        },
        {
            "id": "121202",
            "Libraries": [
                "cpa_sample_code_s.so",
                "stv_test_code_s.so"
            ],
            "Commands": [
                "qaeMemInit",
                "icp_sal_userStartMultiProcess(\"SSL\",CPA_FALSE)",
                "runDcTestPerf(3,0,2,1,1,1,65536,1,100)"
            ],
            "Label": "runDcTestPerf-Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

I converted the above format from a json file to the below mentioned format in `$myVar`. My variable has a hash table but I am unable to display the values using `$myvar["id"]`. I am very new to powershell. Can anyone please help?

```
$myFile = get-content C:\Users\ssc\Desktop\powershell\activity.json
$myvar = $myFile | ConvertFrom-Json
PS C:\Windows\system32> $myvar
ids                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
{@{id=121100; Libraries=System.Object[]; Commands=System.Object[]; Label=rsaPerformanceTest-Test}, @{id=121103; Libraries=System.Object[]; Commands=System.Object[]; Label=dhPerformanceTest-Test}, @{id=121202; Libraries=System.Object[]; Commands=System.Object[]; Label=runDcTestPerf-Test}}
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Looks like `$myvar` is _not_ a hashtable, but rather an object with an `ids` property that contains an array of objects. How did you construct/populate `$myvar` in the first place?

Comment: Please don't post data or code in comments, [update your post instead](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68816689/edit)

Comment: A json content is given as which has been converted from Json and got this format. Requirement is to print the contents of the id taking id as input. It does not have array as there are no array brackets () are used. It has hash table as we use @{} are used. Could you help me please @Mathias R. Jessen

Comment: sure.. @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: `@{PropertyName=Value}` in formatted output does _not_ mean that the object represented was a hashtable. Can you post sample input JSON?

Comment: updated the post, could you please help me on proceeding with the scripting..? @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$myvar.ids` currently contains an array of objects - but you can populate your own hashtable, using the `id` property as the key, like this:

```
$myHashtable = @{}
$myvar.ids |ForEach-Object { $myHashtable[$_.id] = $_ }
```

At which point you should be able to resolve each by id:

```
PS ~> $myHashtable["121100"]

id     Libraries                                  Commands
--     ---------                                  --------
121100 {cpa_sample_code_s.so, stv_test_code_s.so} {qaeMemInit, icp_sal_userStartMultiProcess("SSL",CPA_FALSE), ...}
```

Comment: This is a huge help, it is working, thank you lots.. @MathiasR.Jessen